# Showing $ \sum_{k=p} ^n {n-p \choose k-p} \frac{p^k}{k^p} \ge \frac{(p+1)^n}{(n+1)^p}$ for $0\leq p\leq n$

Tags: inequality, summation, binomial-coefficients

> Let $n$ be a natural number, and $ 0 \le p\le n$. How can the following be shown?
> $$ \sum_{k=p} ^n {n-p \choose k-p} \frac{p^k}{k^p} \ge \frac{(p+1)^n}{(n+1)^p}$$

Both sides are obviously equal when $p=0$ or $p=n$.

I have observed by numerics that the left-hand side seems to exceed the right-hand side but by little, not more than $17$%, when $p$ is close to $\frac{n}{2}$, as soon as $n$ is large enough.

Context:  a proof of the above inequality would enable an induction proof for this [other inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1274187/130022).

**Update:** From @Andreas partial answer, we see that a proof would follow if one could show that  $ p \mapsto   f(y(p),p)$ is a concave function of the variable $p$, in the range $[1,n]$, with
$$y(p):= e^{\frac{p-1}{n}}$$ and
$$ f(y,p):= \Big(y^{-\frac{y}{y+p}} \frac{p+y}{p+1} \Big)^n \Big(y^{\frac{y}{y+p}} \frac{n+1}{n+y}\Big)^p$$
since $f(y(1),1)=f(y(n),n)=1$, we would then have $f(y(p),p) \ge 1$ for $1\le p \le n$.

But this far from easy because the second derivative of $f(y(p),p)$ is awful.

Comment: Consider
$$f(p) = \sum_{k=p}^n \binom{n - p}{k - p}\frac{p^k}{k^p}(n + 1)^p - (p + 1)^n.$$It seems $f(p) \le f(p + 1)$ for all $2\le p \le n - 2$. (The cases $p = 0, 1, n-1, n$ are verified directly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the integral representation obtained by Andreas we want to show $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\frac{p^n}{n^p} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{p-1} e^{-x}  \left( 1 + \frac{e^{\frac{x}{n}}}{p} \right)^{n-p}  {\rm d}x \geq \frac{(p+1)^n}{(n+1)^p}$$
that is, after substituting $x=\frac{n}{n+1}u$ and using $$\left(1+\frac{e^{\frac{u}{n+1}}}{p}\right)^{n-p} \geq \left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^{n-p} e^{\frac{(n-p)u}{(n+1)(p+1)}}$$
for $n\geq p> 0$
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\frac{p^n}{(n+1)^p} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{p-1} e^{-\frac{n}{n+1}u}  \left( 1 + \frac{e^{\frac{u}{n+1}}}{p} \right)^{n-p} \,  {\rm d}u \\
\geq \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\frac{p^p(p+1)^{n-p}}{(n+1)^p} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{p-1} e^{-\frac{n}{n+1}u}  e^{\frac{(n-p)u}{(n+1)(p+1)}} \, {\rm d}u \\
=\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\frac{p^p(p+1)^{n-p}}{(n+1)^p} \frac{(p+1)^p}{p^p} \, \Gamma(p) = \frac{(p+1)^n}{(n+1)^p} \, .$$

Comment: That is much more direct and simple!  The key inequality which is used her is just $e^{\frac{x}{n}} -\Big(e^{\frac{x}{n}}\Big)^{\frac{1}{p+1}} \ge 0$. I will accept this answer.  Thanks also  to @Andreas for providing the other key which is the integral representation.

Comment: Diger, this is really nice! Your lower bound to $\left(1+\frac{e^{\frac{u}{n+1}}}{p}\right)^{n-p}$ has the same value and slope at $u=0$. I was too afraid (-; to do so and instead enforced these conditions at $x=p-1$. This resulted in my bound in up to 17% excess to the true value, whereas   in your solution this excess is exactly being eaten up, to give the desired inequality - this time analytically.  It helps not to be too afraid ....

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite $I$, the LHS in the task, as:

$$
I = \sum_{k=p} ^n {n-p \choose k-p} \frac{p^k}{k^p} =\sum_{k=p} ^n {n-p \choose n - k} \frac{p^k}{k^p} = \\
= \sum_{m=0}^{n-p}\frac{p^{n-m}}{(n-m)^p} {n-p \choose m} = \frac{p^n}{n^p}\sum_{m=0}^{n-p}\frac{p^{-m}}{(1-\frac{m}{n})^p} {n-p \choose m} $$

Now notice the following integral representation, derived from tabular integration by parts, which can be found in (only the German) Wikipedia [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partielle_Integration#Summendarstellung):

$$
\frac{1}{a^p} = \frac{1}{(p-1)!}\int_{x=0}^{\infty} x^{p-1} e^{-a x} dx \tag{1}
$$

Using that representation, we can identify $a = 1 - \frac{m}{n}$ and solve the following sum:

$$
S(x) = \frac{p^n}{n^p}\sum_{m=0}^{n-p}{p^{-m}}e^{\frac{m}{n}x} {n-p \choose m} $$

and then retrieve the result by integrating:

$$
I = \frac{1}{(p-1)!}\int_{x=0}^{\infty} x^{p-1} e^{-x} S(x) dx \tag{2}
$$

We obtain $S(x)$ by the Binomial theorem:
$$
S(x) = \frac{p^n}{n^p} \Big[ 1 + \frac{e^{\frac{x}{n}}}{p} \Big]^{n-p}\\
I = 
\frac{1}{(p-1)!}\frac{p^n}{n^p} \int_{x=0}^{\infty} x^{p-1} e^{-x}  \Big[ 1 + \frac{e^{\frac{x}{n}}}{p} \Big]^{n-p}  dx  $$
where $I$ were a full result after integration. Unfortunately, I do not see how the integration can be performed, so instead I considered a lower bound. The arguments are as follows:

The integral kernel in (2) is $x^{p-1} e^{-x} $ which has its maximum at $x = p-1$, so the "most important" part of the integrand is about that $x$ and any approximation of $S(x)$ should be exact there.

We therefore seek to approximate, in $S(x)$, the base $f(x) = 1 + \frac{e^{\frac{x}{n}}}{p}$ by a lower bound $g(x) = b e^{c x}$ with the properties $f(x=x_0) = g(x=x_0)$ and $f'(x=x_0) = g'(x=x_0)$. We can then choose $x_0 = p-1$ to meet the condition above, see the discussion below.

Straightforward calculation gives
$$
c = \frac{\frac{1}{pn} e^{\frac{x_0}{n}}}{1 + \frac{e^{\frac{x_0}{n}}}{p} } \quad ; \quad b = \frac{1 + \frac{e^{\frac{x_0}{n}}}{p} }{e^{c x_0}}
$$
Note that, comparing the exponents in $f(x)$ and $g(x)$,  indeed $c < \frac{1}{n}$ so $g(x)$ is a lower bound to $f(x)$ for all $x \ge 0$.

Let us first remark that an idea not followed here is to set $x_0 = 0$. This gives $c = \frac{1}{n (p+1)}$ and $b = 1 +  \frac{1}{p}$, which leads to the approach followed in Diger's answer.

Setting, as discussed above,   $x_0 = p-1$, leads to
$$
c = \frac{\frac{1}{pn} e^{\frac{p-1}{n}}}{1 + \frac{e^{\frac{p-1}{n}}}{p} } \quad ; \quad b = \frac{1 + \frac{e^{\frac{p-1}{n}}}{p} }{e^{c(p-1)}}
$$
Continuing with these values, we can now write a lower bound for the integration (2):
$$
I > 
\frac{1}{(p-1)!}\frac{p^n}{n^p} \int_{x=0}^{\infty} x^{p-1} e^{-x} \Big[ be^{cx} \Big]^{n-p}   dx = 
\frac{b^{n-p}}{(p-1)!}\frac{p^n}{n^p} \int_{x=0}^{\infty} x^{p-1} e^{-x(1- c(n-p))}  dx
$$
Again, it can be verified directly that $1- c(n-p) > 0$. We can now use the formula (1) again, this time identifying $a = 1- c(n-p)$. This results in

$$
I > 
\frac{b^{n-p}}{(1-c(n-p))^p}\frac{p^n}{n^p}  = \frac{(p+1)^{n}}{(n+1)^{p}}\frac{\big(\frac{p}{p+1} \big)^n}{\big(\frac{n}{n+1}\big)^p} 
\frac{b^{n-p}}{(1-c(n-p))^p}
$$
So in order to establish  the given inequality $
I >  \frac{(p+1)^{n}}{(n+1)^{p}}
$ we need that

$$
I_2 = \frac{\big(\frac{p}{p+1} \big)^n}{\big(\frac{n}{n+1}\big)^p} 
\frac{b^{n-p}}{(1-c(n-p))^p} \ge  1
$$
Inserting $b$ and $c$ we find that $I_2 = 1$ holds with equality for $\{p=1 \; ; \; \forall n\}$ and for $p=n$. Let us write $p = 1 + q (n-1)$, then if we show that $I_2$ holds for all $n$ and for $0 \leq q \leq 1$, we are done.

I haven't done this yet, but it is just a remaining algebraic task. Numerical simulations show that it is true, illustrated in the following contour plots of $I_2$, for small $n$ and larger $n$:

[image]

[image]

The maximum deviation is about 16 %. Since OP has stated in the task that the original maximum deviation is about 17 %, this shows that the above  lower bound to $S(x)$ almost doesn't change the integral $I$,  verifying the arguments for the chosen approximation.

Comment: The formula (1) can be easily deduced from the definiton of the classical Euler gamma funciton \begin{equation*}
\Gamma(z)=\int_0^{\infty}t^{z-1}\textrm{e}^{-t}\textrm{d}\,t, \quad \Re(z)>0.
\end{equation*}

Comment: I understand that $c\lt \frac{1}{n}$, but I don't quite see why this implies that $b e^{cx} \le 1+\frac{e^{\frac{x}{n}}}{p}$ for all $x \ge 0.$ Would you explain more?

Comment: @RenéGy You have that $f(p−1)=g(p−1)$ where both functions have the same slope $f′_{p−1}$. Observe that under these conditions, $f'(x) = {f'_{p-1} \cdot e^{\frac{x-(p-1)}{n}}}$ and $g'(x) = { f'_{p-1}\cdot e^{c{(x-(p-1))}}}$. With $\frac1n>c$ this means that, for $x > p−1$, $f$ rises faster than $g$ which implies that $f(x)≥g(x)$. In the same vein, for $0\le x < p−1$, $f$ rises slower than $g$ which also implies that $f(x)≥g(x)$, since the above conditions will be met at $x=p-1$.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  This is now more clear.  I think this argument also requires that both $f_p$ and $g_p$ be increasing functions of $x$, which is obvious, and that $f_p(0) =1+\frac{1}{p} \ge g_p(0)$.

Comment: This later requirement can be shown to hold true in the following way:  first note that $f_1(0) = g_1(0)$ and consider the function $h_p(y)= \frac{p+y}{p\cdot y^{\frac{y}{y+p}}}$. It is quite easy to show that $h_p$ is a decreasing function of $y$. Now let $y(q):= e^{\frac{q-1}{n}}$, it is an increasing function of $q$ and then $h_p(y(q))$ is a decreasing function of $q$, therefore $h_p(y(q)) \le h_p(y(1))=  h_p(1)=f_p(0) $, in particular, when $q=p$, we have $h_p(y(p)) \le  f_p(0) $, that is $g_p(0) \le  f_p(0) $.

Comment: Would you also give more details for the proof that $I_2 \ge 1$?  thanks!

Comment: @RenéGy You don't need that $f(0) > g(0)$, once you have that, for$x<p-1$, $f(x)$ is appoaching everywhere with smaller positive slope than $g(x)$ the common point $f(p-1) = g(p-1)$.

Comment: For $I_2 \ge 1$ I took the derived formula for $I_2$ and inserted the derived $b$ an $c$, the result is plotted. I don't have an arithmetic proof yet.

Comment: Indeed showing that $I_2 \ge 1$ does not seem more easy than the original inequality.

Comment: @RenéGy Yes, the structure of $I_2$  is not straightforward. In any case, $I_2$ is a  result in closed form, which in itself is advantageous to the original inequality - which is a sum which has  to be evaluated for each separate case of $n$ and $p$.